# Getting an error while interpreting lambda in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, interpreter

I am trying to interpret lambda in scheme. Here is my code:

```
(define get-operator (lambda (op-symbol)
  (cond
   ((equal? op-symbol '+) +)
   ((equal? op-symbol '-) -)
   ((equal? op-symbol '*) *)
   ((equal? op-symbol '/) /)
   (else (error "interpret: operator not implemented -->" op-symbol)))))

(define (apply-lambda clos actuals)
  (let* ((lam (cadr clos))
         (def-env (caddr clos))
         (formals (cadr lam))
         (body (caddr lam))
         (new-env (bind-all formals actuals def-env)))
    (val-body new-env)))


(define interpret (lambda (e env)
  (cond
   ((number? e) e)
   ((symbol? e) (get-value e env))
   ((not (list? e)) (error "interpret: cannot evaluate -->" e))
   ((if-stmt? e) (if (eq? (cadr e) 0)
                     (interpret (cadddr e) env)
                     (interpret (caddr e) env)))
   ((let-stmt? e) ;;GoZoner's part of code
    (let ((names (map car  (cadr e)))
          (inits (map cadr (cadr e))))
      ;; Evaluate inits in env
      (let ((vals (map (lambda (init) (interpret init env)) inits)))
        ;; Extend env with names+vals
        (let ((new-env (append (map cons names vals) env)))
          ;; Eval body in new env
          (interpret (caddr e) new-env)))))

   ((lambda-stmt? e) (apply-lambda e env))
   (else
    (let ((operands (map interpret (cdr e) (make-list (length (cdr e)) env)))
          (operator (get-operator (car e))))
      (apply operator operands))))))
```

When I try the input `((lambda (n) (+ n 2)) 5)`, I get an error saying "The object `()`, passed as an argument to `safe-car` is not a pair". Why can this be the case?. I am sure that `lambda-stmt?` function works well so I did not write it here, there is something wrong with the interpretation of `apply-lambda` but I cannot find it.

Comment: Can you edit the above code to say ';; GoZoner's Code' right after `(let-stmt? e)`?

Comment: Is your only use of `lambda` going to be a function call?  Or are you expecting to handle something like `(let ((func (lambda ...))) (func ...))`

Comment: I am trying to implement <lambda> -> ( lambda ( <formal_list> ) <expr> ) , <expr> -> NUMBER
| IDENT
| <if>
| <let>
| <letstar>
| <lambda>
| <application> , <let> -> ( let ( <var_binding_list> ) <expr> ) , <var_binding_list> -> ( IDENT <expr> ) <var_binding_list>
| ( IDENT <expr> ) ,
<formal_list> -> IDENT <formal_list>
| IDENT

Comment: @GoZoner so it seems like just a function call, not really needing (let ((func (lambda ...))) (func ...))

Comment: You better clarify.  It looks like `lambda` is an `<expr>` (as it is in real Scheme).  Up to this point you've only had operators in a function call position (like `(+ 1 2)`).  Now you may have `lambda` directly or other expressions that return a `lambda`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreting `lambda` itself is trivial.

```
(define (make-closure formals body env)
  `(CLOSURE ,formals ,body ,env))
(define closure-formals cadr)
(define closure-body    caddr)
(define closure-env     cadddr)

(define (procedure? thing)
  (and (pair? thing) (eq? 'CLOSURE (car thing))))
```

and then in the interpreter:

```
((lambda-stmt? e) (make-closure (cadr e) (caddr) env))
```

You'll then have to change application of a function/operator (your 'else' clause) to deal with a procedure (besides just mathematical operations).  And, you'll need to apply the procedure to its arguments when called - but that is *a lot* like `let` (bind `lambda` formals to arguments, interpret the `lambda` body in the new environment).

[adding...]

I'd start thinking like this:

```
(define (make-primitive name)
  `(PRIMITIVE ,name))
(define primitive-name cadr)
(define (primitive? thing)
  (and (pair? thing) (eq? 'PRIMITIVE (car thing))))

(define top-level-env
  (map (lambda (op) (cons op (make-primitive op))) '(+ - * /)))

(define (interpret e env)
  (cond ((number? e) ...)
        ((symbol? e) ...)
        ((null?   e) (error "interpreter: cannot evaluate --> " e))
        ((if-stmt? e) ...)
        ;; other syntax (let, lambda, set!, ...)
        ...
        ;; function call
        ((list?   e)
         (let ((ie (map (lambda (e) (interpret e env)) e)
           (let ((operator (car ie))
                 (operands (cdr ie)))
             (cond ((primitive? operator)
                    (let ((function (get-operator (primitive-name operator))))
                      (apply function operands)))
                   ((procedure? operator)
                    ...)
                    (else 'error)))))
       (else 'error)))
```

Comment: thanks, but when i try the input ((lambda (n) (+ n 2)) 5) i am still getting the same error saying that "s6-interpret: operator not implemented --> (lambda (n) (+ n 2)). Why is that still happening?

Comment: Because in your final `else` clause you are calling `get-operator`.  That call only works when the function is a primitive operator (like `+` or `*`).  As soon as you introduce `lambda` you'll have calls like  `(foo 1 2)` where `foo` is bound to a `lambda`.  [This is why I said in my answer "You'll then have to change ..."

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong:

```
(lambda-stmt? e)
```

It should be:

```
(lambda-stmt? (car e))
```

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it but now i get an error saying "The object (), passed as an argument to safe-car is not a pair". Why can this be the case? Thank you

Comment: That depends on the scheme interpreter you're using, check the documentation